# Delphi Tokyo unable to deploy ios app - Invalid ipa

Tags: ios, delphi

I just updated to Delphi Tokyo and I can no longer deploy my app and build an `.ipa` file. If I swap back to Berlin 10.1, I can still deploy. It looks like an issue with PAServer:

> [PAClient Warning] Warning: W0008 Invalid ipa option:
>   myapp.app,myapp.ipa,'iPhone Distribution: user1
>   (12345648)','/Users/macuser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
>   Profiles/54f3535feee5-4db0-45ca-a0d7-878787878434.mobileprovision',2,
>   ignored

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Are you running the version of PA Server which corresponds with your Delphi version?

Comment: Yes latest version 19

Comment: I can run the package on my devices, i just cannot deploy the .ipa

Comment: Seems to be related to my computer. I setup a new machine with only Tokyo and it works fine, must be some old files getting in the way. I will try at some point to remove Berlin from my machine and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix the issue I had to remove my installation of Delphi Berlin, it did not seem to like deploying with that installed. There must have been some sort of configuration file in there interfering with it.